# move_uploaded_file doesn't work, no error

Tags: php, image-processing, file-upload, image-manipulation, gd

I am running running a script which moves an uploaded file with `move_uploaded_file()`. I have done this thousands of times but for some reason it's not working. I have confimred the following:

1. `<form>` using `method="post"` and correct `enctype`
2. correct file referenced from form
3. directory has permissions `777`
4. all the `memory_limit`, `max_execution_time`, etc are set to super high settings to avoid timeouts

Basically, the script below returns with just `Your image is too big.`. I have also enabled ALL errors to display and still don't get an error. Any ideas?

```
$time = time();
$target_path = "/absolute/path/to/temp/directory/temp/";

$target_path = $target_path.$time.'.jpg'; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {            

} else{
        $error .= '<li>Your image is too big.</li>';
}
```

Using 1and1 hosting with the php.ini hack :P

**UPDATE 1**

I would like to add that response from the script occurs exactly after 60 seconds.

**UPDATE 2**

We might be getting somewhere with this. Just `print_r($_FILES)` and this is the result of the array:

```
Array ( 
    [image] => Array ( 
        [name] => P2120267.JPG 
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 1 
        [size] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

So that leads me to believe that the file isn't be uploaded correctly to the server or something? I have checked and the post form is `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. So, from what I can tell, the file isn't being uploaded to the server's temp area?

**UPDATE 3**

Noticed the `[error] => 1` in the above array. This is apparently down to [the filesize being larger than the `upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). However, when i set this as `128M`, I get a white screen of death after 60 seconds. The file I'm uploading is 2.5MB

Here is my php.ini file:

```
register_globals=off
memory_limit = 128M 
max_execution_time=3600 
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize= 128M
```

**UPDATE 4**

With details above, it appears that I am getting a WSOD, but the image is being upoaded. So, how to stop the WSOD? I can't find any errors related anywhere.

**UPDATE 5 - FOUND IT!**

Shame on me for not giving you guys all the code. It looks like its to do with this line:

```
resizeImage($feedBurnerStatsSource, PHOTOMSGDIR.'temp/'.$time.'-tmp.jpg',$width,$height);
```

In the following code:

```
function resizeImage($source, $destination = NULL,$wdt, $height = NULL){
    if(empty($height)){
            // Height is nit set so we are keeping the same aspect ratio.
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source);
            if($width > $height){
                    $w = $wdt;
                    $h = ($height / $width) * $w;
                    $w = $w;
            }else{
                    $w = $wdt;
                    $h = $w;
                    $w = ($width / $height) * $w;
            }
    }else{
            // Both width and Height are set.
            // this will reshape to the new sizes.
            $w = $wdt;
            $h = $height;
    }
    $source_image = @file_get_contents($source) or die('Could not open'.$source);
    $source_image = @imagecreatefromstring($source_image) or die($source.' is not a valid image');
    $sw = imagesx($source_image);
    $sh = imagesy($source_image);
    $ar = $sw/$sh;
    $tar = $w/$h;
    if($ar >= $tar){
            $x1 = round(($sw - ($sw * ($tar/$ar)))/2);
            $x2 = round($sw * ($tar/$ar));
            $y1 = 0;
            $y2 = $sh;
    }else{
            $x1 = 0;
            $y1 = 0;
            $x2 = $sw;
            $y2 = round($sw/$tar);
    }
    $slate = @imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h) or die('Invalid thumbnail dimmensions');
    imagecopyresampled($slate, $source_image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $w, $h, $x2, $y2);
    // If $destination is not set this will output the raw image to the browser and not save the file
    if(!$destination) header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    @imagejpeg($slate, $destination, 75) or die('Directory permission problem');
    ImageDestroy($slate);
    ImageDestroy($source_image);
    if(!$destination) exit;
    return true;
}
```

So, WSOD means that its some sort of die without a message. Any ideas?

Comment: Try a `print_r($_FILES);` to see the complete FILES array. It might contain an error code. Your error message doesn't really make sense btw, because you are not doing a size check and *every* error condition will return "image too big"

Comment: File name may not be valid.  Is that file key set?

Comment: If you don't get any error messages there, try `copy()` instead of `move_uploaded_file()`. Also have a look at the `error.log` in such cases.

Comment: That target_path looks particularly strange, is error_reporting on ?

Comment: try `echo` on `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` and `$target_path` in `else` block to check are paths correct.

Comment: as seen above, the $_FILES array is missing temp_name. So what now?

Comment: you have an error. Now time for the manual for explanation. It's pretty clear.

Comment: what does phpinfo() says of these values?

Comment: What does Apache / PHP's error log say?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to verify is the `post_max_filesize` set to a high level? Because according to php.net:

> **If the size of post data is greater than post_max_size, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.** This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the `$_GET` variable to the script processing the data, i.e. `<form action="edit.php?processed=1">`, and then checking if `$_GET['processed']` is set.

Something to consider.

for more info see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and scroll down to the `post_max_filesize` section

**UPDATE**

In my experience if you're getting a WSOD it's usually do to `error_reporting` and `display_errors` being turned off OR the `memory_limit` being reached. In the script at the top I usually set the `memory_limit` to 1024M to verify that isn't the problem and the turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors`... so put this before the file upload:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or E_STRICT
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
```

That normally gets rid of the WSOD and gives you and error to work with.

**UPDATE**

Have you tried taking off the `@` error suppression in front of all your functions to see they are producing a specific error? Also what are you execution and input timeouts? and Can you verify what headers are being sent? (make sure it is `Content-Type=text/html;`)

Comment: yes, its set to something like 256M. When I add that I get a 'white screen of death' after 60 seconds.

Comment: done all that, still no error and still get the same error = 1

Comment: Ok, the image looks like its being uploaded shortly after the WSOD...but i need to prevent the WSOD.

Comment: have you tried taking off the "@" error suppression in front of all your functions to see they are producing a specific error? Also what are you execution and input timeouts?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the target path to a non temp directory.

After some of the updates here is the resolution:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 4000); // Play with the values
ini_set('max_execution_time', 4000); // Play with the values
```

...add this to the beginning of your file that processes the upload.

Comment: the temp directory it's uploading to is one that I have created myself, not a system temp directory.

Comment: Did you try adding the above? The setting apply to all upload locations.

Answer (score 1):

`[error] => 1` means **The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

So, you have to change your settings.

as for the php.ini file you posted here, it just doesn't affect your PHP. you have to move it somewhere to more proper location

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week, it was just because my server space disk was full!  I hope it will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I wanted to overwrite a file, so I have to delete old file and than it works.