# PHP file upload strange issue

Tags: php, file-upload

While uploading images files on the live server I have stuck in a strange issue that the `move_uploaded_files()` function returns true but the image does not get uploaded.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],'./shot_images/'.$_FILES["img"]["name"])){
  echo "Success";
}
```

Here, when executed, prints "Success" but the file is not being uploaded on the specified location.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Does PHP has write rights on /shot_images/?

Comment: @powtac this is wrong question to ask.

Comment: Test it with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Comment: I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655859/move-uploaded-file-doesnt-work-no-error

Comment: @Awea that's the opposite problem. `move_uploaeded_file` there returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `move_uploaded_file` is returning `true` then that indicates the file *was* moved successfully. Let's try some debugging. What happens when you use the following code:

```
$dest = "./shot_images/{$_FILES["img"]["name"]}";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],$dest)){
  $realpath = realpath($dest);
  $filesize = filesize($realpath);
  echo "Success! Uploaded a $filesize file to $realpath";
}
```

I suspect it is working, it's just not going where you expect...

If this is the case, it might be due to `'./shot_images/' -- personally I rarely (if ever) use relative paths like that. I find it eliminates confusion if I reference the path to the script:

```
$dest = dirname(__FILE__)."/shot_images/{$_FILES["img"]["name"]}";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"],$dest)){
```