# move_uploaded_file doesn't work

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image from an HTML form but it doesn't upload it to my folder.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
</form>
$post_image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/".$post_image;
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$location);
```

This is the folder structure:

```
root
   images ----> destination for upload
   includes
        admin ----> i am working here
```

I also tried using a path like this, but it didn't work either.

```
$location = "../../images".$post_image;
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the `images` folder? Or rather, does your webserver's user have write access?

Comment: I hope you put `<?php ?>` tags in your php code :)

Comment: check this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655859/move-uploaded-file-doesnt-work-no-error

Comment: Guys i am sorry, but problem was in my FTP client (total commander) which doesn't show new files for some reason.
when i connected on Web FTP all images were there.
thanks for suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remember that you have permission to create file in test folder

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
<pre>
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    var_dump($_FILES);
    $post_image= $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/".$post_image;
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$location);
}
?>
</pre>
```